# How does Vector3.MoveTowards work in Unity?

Tags: unity

What I mean is that I don't understand what each part does, like in the example in the API, it didn't give much on what did what! I kinda need this for an aim script in a shooter game I'm working on. Any help will be good, but a direct answer would be great!

Comment: To me it seems a little unclear what you are asking. Are you having trouble with the theory of that function? The usage? Something else? Could you clarify that and edit it into your question? Thanks.

Comment: I know its usage, but I'm unsure on HOW to use, like in my own script. Thank you for helping me clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the function if you need  to move an object towards a specific position that you know. The function takes in the current position of the object you want to move, the target position you want to reach, and the distance that you want to move towards the object.

So, if for an example  you had an object at position (0, 0, 0), and you wanted to move it to the position (0, 7, 0), 2 units at the time, the function translates the position first from (0, 0, 0) to (0, 2, 0), then to (0, 4, 0), then to (0, 6, 0) and finally to (0, 7, 0). Notice, that in the last step, only one unit was moved. That way, you can safely call the function with values that don't happen to match up at some point.

Now, [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html), can be used for a broad set of things, but for a basic example you could use it to move your player to where the user has clicked their mouse. The Unity docs link shows a very basic example, including a description, which should tell you enough about the usage (you could also try the script out, debug it and see what values get assigned and when).

You would simply feed in `transform.position` as the first parameter, the click position as the second position, and a suitable speed as the final parameter. I'm not an Unity user, so I can't suggest a speed to use off-hand like this. Try out a few different values and see which feels good.

At the basic level, similar functionality can be achieved using a more basic linear interpolation, however this utility function guarantees that you will hit your target and the usage here is quite simple and easy.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Your 4th paragraph answered my issue perfectly. One less thing to complete on strikedown now(my shooter game). I'm still in development.

Comment: Glad to hear that I was able to clarify the usage for you! Don't forget to upvote, and accept my answer after a while as you don't want to discourage other people from answering and providing potentially useful insights.

Comment: @TheMattBat999 Mark as right answer if things worked out for you.

Comment: It won't let me vote to your answer

Comment: You might not have enough rep; don't worry about it.